# left align header

Tags: css, display, text-align

```css
.about-header {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: red;
}

.about-header hr{
    width: 70px;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.about-header h4{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
 <div class="about-header"> <hr> <h4>Our Services</h4> </div>
```

no matter what i do i can't align the header next to hr. I tried text-align: left or float left but they didn't work, I used display:flex to keep them aligned, maybe it's because of that

[I want to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlz8t.png)

Comment: And what exactly do you want to achieve? "*Align*" how?

Comment: Please share screenshots/illustrations of what you currently have and what you want.

Comment: your question makes no sense.  what are you trying to do?  the h4 tag is aligned to hr

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet, and check that it definitely shows the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also do you want just a horizontal line or does it need the semantics that are attached to an hr element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe can work if you use also margin-right: 0;

Comment: .about-header hr{
    width: 70px;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-left: 0;    margin-right: 0;

}